# ValueError: Cannot load NumPy file with pickled data - Troubleshooting allow_pickle=False

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, pickle, valueerror

I am encountering a `ValueError` while attempting to execute a script that involves loading data from NumPy files (`*.npy`). The specific error message is as follows:

```
ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False
```

I believe this issue is related to a mismatch in pickling settings between the saved data and the loading process. The relevant code snippet in the `odir.py` file responsible for loading the data is as follows:

```py
# Code snippet from odir.py
x_train = np.load('odir_training' + '_' + str(image_size) + '.npy')
y_train = np.load('odir_training_labels' + '_' + str(image_size) + '.npy')
# ...
```

Additionally, I am providing a segment from the training script, `odir_inception_v3_training_basic.py`, where the data is loaded:

```py
# Code snippet from odir_inception_v3_training_basic.py
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = odir.load_data(128)
# ...
```

I seek guidance on how to modify either the loading or saving process to address this issue. Your assistance in resolving this discrepancy in pickling settings would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

FileName:- odir.py

```
import numpy as np


def load_data(image_size, index = 0, challenge = 0):
    """Loads the ODIR dataset.

    Returns:
      Tuple of Numpy arrays: `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)`.

    """

    if index == 0:
        x_train = np.load('odir_training' + '_' + str(image_size) + '.npy')
        y_train = np.load('odir_training_labels' + '_' + str(image_size) + '.npy')
    else:
        x_train = np.load('odir_training' + '_' + str(image_size) + '_' + str(index) + '.npy')
        y_train = np.load('odir_training_labels' + '_' + str(image_size) + '_' + str(index) + '.npy')

    if challenge == 0:
        x_test = np.load('odir_testing'+'_' + str(image_size)+'.npy')
        y_test = np.load('odir_testing_labels'+'_' + str(image_size)+'.npy')
    else:
        x_test = np.load('odir_testing_challenge'+'_' + str(image_size)+'.npy')
        y_test = np.load('odir_testing_labels_challenge'+'_' + str(image_size)+'.npy')

    return (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)
```

FileName:-odir_inception_v3_training_basic.py

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import inception_v3
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v1 import SGD

os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'
import secrets
import odir
from odir_advance_plotting import Plotter
from odir_kappa_score import FinalScore
from odir_predictions_writer import Prediction
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
import numpy as np

batch_size = 32
num_classes = 8
epochs = 100
patience = 5

# class_weight = {0: 1.,
#                 1: 1.583802025,
#                 2: 8.996805112,
#                 3: 10.24,
#                 4: 10.05714286,
#                 5: 1.,
#                 6: 1.,
#                 7: 2.505338078}

token = secrets.token_hex(16)
folder = r'test_run'

new_folder = os.path.join(folder, token)

if not os.path.exists(new_folder):
    os.makedirs(new_folder)

base_model = inception_v3.InceptionV3

base_model = base_model(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# Comment this out if you want to train all layers
#for layer in base_model.layers:
#    layer.trainable = False

x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
model.summary()

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file=os.path.join(new_folder, 'model_inception_v3.png'), show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)

defined_metrics = [
    tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
    tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
    tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
    tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
]

# Adam Optimizer Example
# model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
#               optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),
#               metrics=defined_metrics)

# RMSProp Optimizer Example
# model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
#               optimizer='rmsprop',
#               metrics=defined_metrics)

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
print('Configuration Start -------------------------')
print(sgd.get_config())
print('Configuration End -------------------------')
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=defined_metrics)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = odir.load_data(128)

x_test_drawing = x_test

x_train = inception_v3.preprocess_input(x_train)
x_test = inception_v3.preprocess_input(x_test)

class_names = ['Normal', 'Diabetes', 'Glaucoma', 'Cataract', 'AMD', 'Hypertension', 'Myopia', 'Others']

# plot data input
plotter = Plotter(class_names)

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=patience, mode='min', verbose=1)

#class_weight = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(x_train), x_train)

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    shuffle=True, #class_weight= class_weight,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test), callbacks=[callback])

print("saving weights")
model.save(os.path.join(new_folder, 'model_weights.h5'))

print("plotting metrics")
plotter.plot_metrics(history, os.path.join(new_folder, 'plot1.png'), 2)

print("plotting accuracy")
plotter.plot_accuracy(history, os.path.join(new_folder, 'plot2.png'))

print("display the content of the model")
baseline_results = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)
for name, value in zip(model.metrics_names, baseline_results):
    print(name, ': ', value)
print()

# test a prediction
test_predictions_baseline = model.predict(x_test)
print("plotting confusion matrix")
plotter.plot_confusion_matrix_generic(y_test, test_predictions_baseline, os.path.join(new_folder, 'plot3.png'), 0)

# save the predictions
prediction_writer = Prediction(test_predictions_baseline, 400, new_folder)
prediction_writer.save()
prediction_writer.save_all(y_test)

# show the final score
score = FinalScore(new_folder)
score.output()

# plot output results
plotter.plot_output(test_predictions_baseline, y_test, x_test_drawing, os.path.join(new_folder, 'plot4.png'))
```

Comment: When using `np.save` it's the nature of the saved object that determines whether pickling is used or not. It's with `np.load` that `allow_pickle=True` makes a difference. Evidently what you saved contained non-array material that required pickling,

Comment: All that load and model code tells us nothing about the problem `.npy` file,  Including how and what you saved to it.